# Create and Map Home Directory for AD Users using PowerShell in Bulk

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a script to add users to my AD in bulk.
I use a .csv file for this.

So far I am able to add the users in bulk, however I am stuck on how to also create a home directory with the standard homedirectory permissions. If anyone has a solution or tips, I would appreciate that.

my script so far:

```
$pw = read-host "Password" -AsSecureString
Import-CSV F:\Scripts\newusers\usersVoorbeeldDannyWijnsema.csv | foreach `
{New-ADUser `
-Name $_.Name `
-SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName `
-GivenName $_.GivenName `
-Surname $_.Surname `
-DisplayName $_.DisplayName `
-UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName `
-AccountPassword $pw `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
-Enabled $true `
-Path 'OU=N43,OU=Students,DC=example,DC=local' `
-HomeDir ='\\Example-DC01\UserFolders\$($_.SamAccountName)' `
-DriveLetter ='Z:' `
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> $pw = read-host "Password" -AsSecureString 
> Import-CSV F:\Scripts\newusers\usersVoorbeeldDannyWijnsema.csv | foreach {
> New-ADUser -Name $_.Name -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName  -GivenName $_.GivenName  -Surname $_.Surname -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName  -AccountPassword $pw  -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true  -Enabled $true  -Path 'OU=N43,OU=Students,DC=example,DC=local' 
> $homeShare = "Home share path"
> $DriveLetter = "Z:"
> $user = Get-ADUser $_.sAmAccountName
> Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $fullPath -ea Stop
> $homeShare = New-Item -path $fullPath -ItemType Directory -force -ea Stop
> $acl = Get-Acl $homeShare
> $FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
>  $AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
> $InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
> $PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"InheritOnly"
> $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($User.SID, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
> $acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
> Set-Acl -Path $homeShare -AclObject $acl -ErrorAction Stop
> }
> ```

Attribution: https://activedirectoryfaq.com/2017/09/powershell-create-home-directory-grant-permissions/

I modified script found there.

This script creates an ACL object and Grants standard homedirectory permission to each created AD user from CSV.

Comment: Thanks, this got me to solve the issue, thank you very much!